# Javascript Prompt: best practice?

Tags: javascript

I would like to prompt the user for some input on a webpage.

I can't use the builtin Javascript *prompt* function as it is creates security warnings in IE.

Is there a best practice/method/example that people use to recreate this?

The Javascript would need to be embedded in the page, so I'm looking at avoiding weighty external libraries.

Comment: Ended up using this, minus the code that checks for IE7:
http://www.hunlock.com/blogs/Working_around_IE7s_prompt_bug,_er_feature

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest, most user-friendly approach would probably be to create a normal HTML form that you show with JavaScript in response to a click event on a link or button; you'd then hide the form after the data has been submitted.

Comment: @OP: When showing the form, you can even position it absolutely in the middle of the viewport (`position: absolute` and `left` and `top` styles), on top of other content (`z-index` style), with an iframe shim underneath it to prevent clicks anywhere outside the form. More on iframe shims here: http://www.macridesweb.com/oltest/IframeShim.html

Comment: You should render the form with JavaScript, too.

Answer (score 1):

I'd steer away from prompts; they're obtrusive. You could render a form.

Comment: This is basically what the OP said: He doesn't want to use prompt.

Comment: @T.J. Crowder: It's not "basically what the OP said"; he's asking for an example of how to mimic a prompt, and the answer provides it.

Answer (score 1):

I use jQuery plugin [Impromptu](https://github.com/trentrichardson/jQuery-Impromptu). It's nice and unobtrusive and sufficiently lightweight.

Comment: Link is dead, it 404's

Comment: Yes, the website page no longer exists. Replaced with the link to the GitHub repository. Although it doesn't even have a screenshot, and I don't remember myself how that plugin looked. :(